# Retrofit converted POST to GET

Tags: android, post, get, retrofit

I have really strange problem. Use retrofit to send request.

```
@POST("api/v2/reviews/vote/{vote}/dislike/{dislike}")
Single<SimpleResponse> postReviewLike(@Path("vote") Integer vote, @Path("dislike") Integer dislike);
```

This is my request, but when I send it to server - retrofit converted it to GET request. Below photo for a proof:

[image: how it send]

[image: than changed to GET]

Can you suggest, what it can be? And how I can fix it.

With other POST request all is good, if I use @Field.

Comment: What is your error? Are you getting any problem?

Comment: Server expected POST, but retrofit send GET. I sent POST and don't understand, why retrofit changed it and how

Comment: You are behind a proxie.

Comment: Any solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with redirect. Adding '/' `dislike/{dislike}/` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this out using the `@Body` annotation?

```
@POST("api/v2/reviews/vote/{vote}/dislike/{dislike}")
Single<SimpleResponse> postReviewLike(@Body @Path("vote") Integer vote, @Path("dislike") Integer dislike);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and after hours of debugging I finally solved this by making my API URL start with `https` instead of `http`

Note:

1. The SSL should also be installed on your server-side